# Does a whole garage door need to be replaced if the middle bracket broke?

Tags: garage, garage-door

I have an aluminum garage door that looks in great shape; the only problem is one of the brackets in the middle of the garage door broke. I thought someone would be able to weld it back together, but a garage door company said the whole door needs to be replaced.

Is that true? Can't a bracket on an aluminum garage door bracket be fixed without replacing the whole garage door along with permits?

Comment: Do you have any photos for us?  Even if you can't weld it you might be able to rivet or screw replacement hinge backing in place.

Answer (score 1):

You can buy most common parts separately. Replace the part rather than have it welded. Ask at your local hardware store (NOT "big-box" store) for a handyman reference, someone familiar with garage doors. Garage door companies will almost always recommend a new door.

Hey, while you are at your local "mom and pop" store, why don't you pick up a few items and help them stay in business?